# AWS IAM: how to create a condition using global condition keys

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I want to create a policy so that user can only create EC2 keypair with name "test-key-pair*", not key pair with any other name. but looks like there is no such way.

In fact when I create the policy with EC2:CreateKeyPair action, it shows "the action you choose support all resources. ". but I do want to sets some limit. So I click "request conditions", which show the list of some "global condition keys", such as aws:TagKeys.
And I created the following conditions to EC2:CreateKeyPair. my understanding is with this condition, when a user create key pair, only if he set both tag key CostCenter and tag key Department, he can create a key pair, otherwise, he cannot.

However, this condition does not work at all. a user can create key pair without setting any tag key. so I do not know how to use the "global condition keys". I do know how to user service related conditions. 
besides, I do not understand for the resources like key pair, why I am not allowed to restrict the resources using such as: test-key-pair*,

```
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "ec2:CreateKeyPair",
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                "aws:TagKeys": [
                    "CostCenter",
                    "Department"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the link of global condition keys:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html#AvailableKeys.

Comment: Can you please state (in words) what permissions you wish to grant/deny for the User in Amazon Athena?

Comment: John Rotenstein: Thanks for response, my question is not about Athena but us about how to use condition to restrict permission and how to use TagKeys. I have rewritten the original post to make my question clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tags cannot be associated with a keypair.

I tried a few *conditions*, but I was unable to limit the action to a specific Keyname.

So, it doesn't look like you can limit KeyPair creation based on the Key Name.

Some alternatives:

- Use [AWS Service Catalog](https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/servicecatalog/?id=docs_gateway) to provision the resources, with rules
- Create some form of 'front-end' that creates the keypair on their behalf, following certain rules (could be an app, could use Lambda)

Comment: Hi, John Rotenstein, Thanks for trying and answering me. I will try AWS Service Catalog. good to know that.